# How to write data on specified col/index in txt file using java

Tags: java, file

For example I have data:

```
000001!1 |TEST 3     |18   01/22 01/23    |789
```

I will write the data based on specified col/index.
I had been search on internet for the alternative is using string format, but I have been rules that define the specified col on **`txt`** and the data.
the example of the rules are:

> No.Record on col 1,
>   Name on col 12.

How I can do this?
Thank you..

Comment: The short answer is, you want, well, kind of, it's complicated. The simpler solution would have you read the data from the source and either modify it directly or write to a temp file, with the modifications and rename the new file over the old

Comment: yes, that is also a great idea Sir, but my origin data is from db not from txt file. I am sorry, I forgot explain the source of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have fixed sized records in text format. One can use a [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Given the record length and column widths you then can calculate the absolute file position and overwrite bytes padded to the cell width.

This is rather awkward, might fit your use-case or not.

Comment: Thank you Sir, finally I can use seek() function of RandomAccessFile to write on txt with specified col.

Answer (score 1):

I have some pseudo code that might help you for getting the formatted code in the text file ..this is some sort of tabular data

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
    File dir = new File("C:\\Test");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    int SNIndexlength = "Serial_Number".length();
    SNIndexlength = SNIndexlength-3+20;
    fileWriter.write(String.format("%s %20s %20s  \r\n", "Serial_Number", "Name", "Count"));

    List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
    datas.add(new Data("001", "TEST1", 3));
    datas.add(new Data("002", "TEST2", 5));
    datas.add(new Data("003", "TEST3", 7));
    datas.add(new Data("004", "TEST4", 10));
    datas.add(new Data("005", "TEST5", 0));

    for (Data data : datas) {
        fileWriter.write(String.format("%s %"+SNIndexlength+"s %20s  \r\n", data.sNum, data.name, data.count));
    }
    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
}

static class Data{
    public String sNum;
    public String name;
    public int count;   
    public Data(String no, String name, int count){
        this.sNum = no;
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

I have updated the answer where I have changed the writing to text file as dynamic using a collection, Hope it may help.

Comment: Thank u Sir, I have been tried use String.format, but I have rules that explain the mapping data from db and specified col.

Comment: so from Database are you putting your data back into some sort of collection?

Comment: yes, I get my data from db and collect to the array, then I write into txt file with rules of col. and I have been find the procedure using Random Access Files with their seek() function to refer on specified col. My rules of col has been save on db so if there are any changes to the rules of col and the data mapping, user can change the setting for  specified col. and I use the col in seek(long col) from RandomAccessFile.
Thank you for the respons.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
public boolean editFile(AFileObject file, Integer line, Integer col, String value) {
    file.openInReadMode();

    // We write the results in a temporary file
    AFileObject tempFile = AFileObject.getNewTempFile();
    tempFile.openInWriteMode();

    // We start looping until we'll reach the line to edit
    for (int i = 0; ! file.eof() || i < line ; i++) {
        tempFile.write(file.readLine());
    }

    // If we reached the end of file before, do nothing and returns false
    if file.eof() {
        file.close();
        tempFile.delete();
        return false;
    }

    // We edit the line here, then we write it in the temporary file
    // in place of the original line
    String lineToEdit = file.readLine();
    lineToEdit = editLineColumn(lineToEdit, col, value);
    tempFile.write(lineToEdit);

    // Then we write the remaining lines
    while (! file.eof()) {
        tempFile.write(file.readLine());
    }

    // Work done. We just have now to close the files and
    // Replace the source file by the temporary one 
    file.close();
    tempFile.close();
    tempFile.rename(file.getFileName());

    return true;
}

private boolean String editLineColumn(String line, Integer col, String value) {
    // Your code here :)
}
```

As you can see, it's pseudo-code. You'll have to look for the IO package which fits your needs (try with Java.IO one with FileReader and FileWriter objects for example). Start producing your own code, then we'll be able to help.

Comment: Thank u Sir, but the origin my data is from the db not from a txt file, I am sorry, I forgot for explain my origin data.

Comment: I use repository class for getting data from 'SELECT' db and has been save into array. then I write into txt file from the array. but I was confused about how to write data in specified col, because every part of my array data has own specified col rule. Now, I  finally found how to write data on specified col, I use RandomAccessFile and their seek() function. Thanks for the respons. I am sorry for made you confused, I am new in java.